# Can I change a block parameter using another block for conditional execution?

Tags: matlab, model, simulink

I'm wondering whether it is possible to change a block parameter in Simulink (or the value of one saved as a variable) using a different block to enable conditional execution. What I would like to do is have a certain block parameter (in this case, **Counter**) run during the simulation with an initial value, and have it change to a different value if a certain condition is satisfied.

**Ultimately, what I would like to get out of this is to get a Counter block to stop running upon the satisfaction of that condition.**
I'm pretty new to Simulink, but I'll detail some of the stuff I've tried so far:

1. Dashboard switches (Slider, Knob etc.) - I know they're used to
   change tunable parameters of blocks, but they cannot be linked to
   other blocked and can be only be controlled manually.
2. Matlab Function block - didn't seem to work, I'm obviously missing something.

Is it maybe possible to disable a certain block/link when that condition is met? That would be a straight forward approach, but I'm not sure it can be implemented in Simulink. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

So to meet your ultimate goal have you considered to place your counter in an enabled subsytem?

Whenever the requirements are met to stop the counter you simply disable the subsystem and the counter will stop.
On the output port of that enabled subsystem you will have the options to preserve the last value or reset it to certain one.